# The Rauchabzug is beeping, what do I do?

Tags: germany, berlin

I'm new to Germany (Berlin) and I find myself alone in an apartment faced with a Rauchabzug that's making a single constant beep.

As best I can tell from some brief research, this has something to do with smoke extraction in case of fire, but it's been going for a while now, there doesn't seem to be any fire or smoke and the noise is more just irritating than something that seems like an alarm.

What does this mean and what am I suppose to do about it?

It looks roughly like this image I found [on Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rauch-_und_W%C3%A4rmeabzug):

[image]

Comment: This would be the best title seen on the site yet.  And the best nickname  :)

Comment: The device reads "smoke evacuation" and "smash window, press button deeply." Also, the light is showing OK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those *Rauchabzug* buttons control electrical window openers on a skylight. It's only to be pressed in case of fire.

The beeping may mean there's something wrong with the skylight or the opener. You should ask the facility manager (German: *der Hausmeister*) to do something about it.

Answer (score 2):

We were desperate and our landlord was not doing anything. After reading @Janka's answer we tried to open the cover and it worked for a while. But beepings started again.

We kept the cover open but no luck. Then we saw a small button inside. On the board it was written something like "reset". Anyway, I do not encourage anybody to do it, but we pressed that and it worked for good.